# Magento 2 Fail to change form encoding method to enctype='multipart/form-data'

Tags: magento2, forms

added the following codes to `_prepareForm()`, but it can't change to the encoding method to `multipart/form-data`. How to change the encoding method to `multipart/form-data`? Thanks.

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                ],
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `_prepareForm()` function inside, `Package\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Edit\Form.php`

Below is code for that,

```
namespace Package\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Edit;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
       $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        [
        'data' => [
                   'id' => 'edit_form',
                   'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                   'method' => 'post',
                   'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                  ]
        ]
    );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Your problem are solved using above changes.
Thanks.

Comment: after adding $form->setUseContainer(true); , the encoding method changed to multipart/form-data but I can't click the save button. The button gives no response. Thanks

Comment: @Ricky.C how did you solve that problem?