# Magento 2 : How to Change Form encoding?

Tags: magento2, forms, magento2.2.3, override-block

I would like add **multipart-form/data** to Magento2's Admin Form.

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

 <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form"
 type="Vednor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form" />

 </config>
```

I've override below file

> magento-customer/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form.php

**TO**

> Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Vivek\ShopAsGroup\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

 use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
 use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\Form as DataForm;


 class Form extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form
 {
protected $formFactory;


public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer $taxCustomer,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxHelper,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface, 
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory $groupDataFactory,

    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_taxCustomer = $taxCustomer;
    $this->_taxHelper = $taxHelper;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->groupDataFactory = $groupDataFactory;
    $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

protected function _prepareForm()
{
   parent::_prepareForm(); //add this
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
   $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
    [
    'data' => [
           'id' => 'edit_form',
           'action' => $this->getData('action'),
           'method' => 'post',
           'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
          ]
    ]
);
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return $this; //chnage this
   }
   }
```

I did **upgrade**  and **Deploy** but it not seems to be working for me.

Took reference from [Magento StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96404/magento-2-fail-to-change-form-encoding-method-to-enctype-multipart-form-data)

What i am missing ? Any Guide..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @No one has idea about this ??

Answer (score 1):

IN your `Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form.php` file change as per below. And add right class for extending

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;


class Form extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
       parent::_prepareForm(); //add this
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
       $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        [
        'data' => [
               'id' => 'edit_form',
               'action' => $this->getData('action'),
               'method' => 'post',
               'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
              ]
        ]
    );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this; //chnage this
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try same way you suggested before, After i return `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic::_prepareForm()`, Form stopped loading.

Comment: @LazyCoder check updated code

Comment: Now **Fatal Error** `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\m2fresh\app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form.php on line 43`

I've updated my code for `Form.php` check post.

Comment: @LazyCoder remove generated folder and fire di:compile command

Comment: If i am extending `\Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form` instead of `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic` than i am receiving error while compilation

Comment: That is `Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form`
**Incompitable argument type: \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer\**

`Actual type array; File Block/Adminhtml/group\edit\form.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code inside your class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

class Form extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
       parent::_prepareForm();

       $form = $this->getForm();
       $form->setData('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did try same way But No luck .:(

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

**Step:1** Create file `di.xml` at location `xxx/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` & add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form"/>
</config>
```

**Step:2** Create `Form.php` file at location `xxx/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit` and add below code in this file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

/**
 * Adminhtml customer groups edit form
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer
     */
    protected $_taxCustomer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_taxHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_groupRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $groupDataFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer $taxCustomer
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxHelper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory $groupDataFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Customer $taxCustomer,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory $groupDataFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $formFactory,
            $taxCustomer,
            $taxHelper,
            $groupRepository,
            $groupDataFactory,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form for render
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

        $groupId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_GROUP_ID);
        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface $customerGroup */
        if ($groupId === null) {
            $customerGroup = $this->groupDataFactory->create();
            $defaultCustomerTaxClass = $this->_taxHelper->getDefaultCustomerTaxClass();
        } else {
            $customerGroup = $this->_groupRepository->getById($groupId);
            $defaultCustomerTaxClass = $customerGroup->getTaxClassId();
        }

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Group Information')]);

        $validateClass = sprintf(
            'required-entry validate-length maximum-length-%d',
            \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement::GROUP_CODE_MAX_LENGTH
        );
        $name = $fieldset->addField(
            'customer_group_code',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'code',
                'label' => __('Group Name'),
                'title' => __('Group Name'),
                'note' => __(
                    'Maximum length must be less then %1 characters.',
                    \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement::GROUP_CODE_MAX_LENGTH
                ),
                'class' => $validateClass,
                'required' => true
            ]
        );

        if ($customerGroup->getId() == 0 && $customerGroup->getCode()) {
            $name->setDisabled(true);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'tax_class_id',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'tax_class',
                'label' => __('Tax Class'),
                'title' => __('Tax Class'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->_taxCustomer->toOptionArray(),
            ]
        );

        if ($customerGroup->getId() !== null) {
            // If edit add id
            $form->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id', 'value' => $customerGroup->getId()]);
        }

        if ($this->_backendSession->getCustomerGroupData()) {
            $form->addValues($this->_backendSession->getCustomerGroupData());
            $this->_backendSession->setCustomerGroupData(null);
        } else {
            // TODO: need to figure out how the DATA can work with forms
            $form->addValues(
                [
                    'id' => $customerGroup->getId(),
                    'customer_group_code' => $customerGroup->getCode(),
                    'tax_class_id' => $defaultCustomerTaxClass,
                ]
            );
        }

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setId('edit_form');
        $form->setAction($this->getUrl('customer/group/save'));
        $form->setMethod('post');
        $form->setEnctype('multipart/form-data');
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step:3** After run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Note:** I have added above code vendor name is **Vendor** & module name is **ModuleName**. Please change per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add / Edit custom module's di.xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Form" type="Custom\Override\Block\User\Edit\Form" />
</config>
```

2. Create Preference File at path Custom\Override\Block\User\Edit\Form.php. Add below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Custom\Override\Block\User\Edit;

/**
 * Adminhtml permissions user edit form
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Form extends \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Form
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create([
            'data' => 
                [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' //Updated this
                ]
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;
    }
}
```