# Magento 2 User Admin image upload $_FILES empty

Tags: adminform, magento2.2.4, admin-user

I'am trying to add a field to upload image for specific user. I add field but problem is when I try save User. Image isn't uploaded and I got exception that $_FILES is empty. I followed these instructions:

[Magento2 : Admin module Image upload code to display form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86125/magento2-admin-module-image-upload-code-to-display-form)

How to successfully upload image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look like, the enctype for the form still not set, try update the code

```
  $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
```

to be like this :

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create(
    [
    'data' => [
               'id' => 'id_form',
               'method' => 'post',
               'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
              ]
    ]
);

....
....
....

$form->setUseContainer(true);
$this->setForm($form);
```

you can reference to this link : [Magento 2 Fail to change form encoding method to enctype='multipart/form-data'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96404/magento-2-fail-to-change-form-encoding-method-to-enctype-multipart-form-data#answer-96406)

hope this can solve your problem